# Does JSP file needs entry in web.xml

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have referred several websites but still I am not getting the exact picture. If we create a servlet and used in html form action tag we create an entry in web.xml, if we do the same for jsp file should we need to make an entry in web.xml?

Whenever we create a new jsp file, do we need to make an entry in web.xml file? When we should make an entry and when there is no necessity in doing it.

Comment: please have a try and meditation. If still have problem in your test system, then ask question.   there is no need to add entry or register pages in `web.xml`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need, because if your server accept request from client. It will check web.xml file in your project. if do not find the mapping, it will check another web.xml in tomcat server under $TOMCAT_HOME/conf foder. In this file, you will find the config

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.jspx</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

This config will be used when you request jsp files.

Comment: But how it find the actual JSP file location. In case with servlet we will the provide exact location of servlet in servlet-class tag. In case with JSP how will it find the location if I give action="test.jsp" in form tag.

Comment: In web.xml,you will find the config  <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>  JspServlet will precompile jsp file and process request with servlet while the jsp file compiled.

Answer (score 1):

> If we create a servlet and used in html form action tag we create an entry in web.xml, if we do the same for jsp file should we need to make an entry in web.xml?

No need , It will search for the path of the file given and opens it.

> Whenever we create a new JSP file, do we need to make an entry in web.xml file?

Again no need for that.

But If you want to filter the requests for that jsp you need filter mapping like

```
<filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>Some.jsp</url-pattern>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Whenever we create a new jsp file, do we need to make an entry in
>   web.xml file?

**No,** you don't need, jsp file can be directly invoked by URL.